# Converting MySQL Query to Sqlite (SUBSTRING_INDEX)

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite, substring

I am working on a C# project which has a library to perform common tasks among various project.

I have a function in the library which gets a list of alarms from a table. This query is done in MySQL but I now need the same functionality with an SQLite database.

Below is the query I am  trying to port from MySQL to Sqlite.

```
SELECT id, min(date) as min_date, max(date) as max_date, type, partMsg, level, page, COUNT(partMsg) AS msgCount FROM (SELECT id, date, type, SUBSTRING_INDEX(message, ':', 1) AS partMsg, level, page FROM alarms a WHERE acknowledged='0') p GROUP BY partMsg
```

At the moment when I run this query on the Sqlite database it throws an exception stating that SUBSTRING_INDEX isn't a valid function. Does SQLite have an alternative function that would  do the same as this.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT id, min(date) as min_date, max(date) as max_date, type, partMsg, level, page, COUNT(partMsg) AS msgCount FROM (SELECT id, date, type, substr(message, ':', 1) AS partMsg, level, page FROM alarms a WHERE acknowledged='0') p GROUP BY partMsg
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It sorts of work but only showing the one group. I have ``alarm info:`` ``alarm warning:`` `alarm medium`` so it should 3 rows, but its only showing 1 row for alarm info: